# Question 'asked' timestamp is newer than first answer timestamp

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89015/luggage-storage-options-at-heathrow-airport) appears to have been asked on 01-Mar-17 10:17 UTC, while the answer has a time stamp of 27-Feb-2017 11:28 UTC (The mouse-over mentions Z at the end of timestamp so I assume that means UTC).

Here's a screenshot
[image: question as seen on my computer]

I can't tell if the question has been migrated from another site by looking at it.

So how is this possible that the question was answered before it was asked?

Comment: I'd suspect it being merged with another question, perhaps?

Comment: @MarkMayo is correct, the timeline reveals that the question was merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has indeed been merged with a question by the same author. The merged post has since been deleted, hence the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I totally missed the "Merged" entry in edit history.